# Powershell where-object doesn't work

Tags: powershell

I have this Powershell code that works in 2013, but it doesn't work in 2010, although am using a functionality that supposed to work in 2010, my problem is with the where-object, it's not really filtering anything, and retrieving 0 results:

```
$ListTitle  = Read-Host "Enter the title of your list, then click Enter key..."
$MyList = $Web.Lists[$ListTitle]
$cts = $MyList.ContentTypes
foreach($ct in $cts)
{
    Write-Host $ct.Name
    $items = $MyList.Items | Where-Object {$_.ContentType.Name -eq $ct.Name}
    Write-Host "Count is "  $items.Count
}
```

Here $items count is null, although when trying this on 2013 environment it works perfect.

Comment: are you seeing any content type name on the line before where-object? in 2010 do you have items in the list? also try to replace where-object to ? {}( both are same just for checking)

Comment: Hi, Waqar, thanks for your reply. Yes, the same lists in both environments with same content type, If I remove the where-object, I could retrieve all results, can you try to check it on your 2010 machine? I have tried it on 2 2010 machines, same case.

Answer (score 0):

It might have been changed in some updates since 2014, but it is working now in 2018:

```
cls

$web = $null
$web = Get-SPWeb "https://contoso.com"
$web.title

$list = $null
$list = $web.lists["Test documents"]
$list.title

$list.Items | Where-Object {$_.ContentType.Name -eq "Custom content type" }

$web.Dispose();
Write-Host "End" -BackgroundColor DarkGreen -ForegroundColor Green
```